# How to recognize words which are not in the grammar

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition

I am trying to make a speech recognition app using c#(windows form).

Here is the code I am using

```
//recognizing speech
SpeechRecognitionEngine r = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
//then load the grammar
r.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder
        (new Choices("hello","how are you","nice to meet you")))
        { Name = "speechGrammar" });

r.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set the input of the speech recognizer to the default audio device
r.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // recognize speech asynchronous

//adding a event handler
r.SpeechRecognized += r_SpeechRecognized;
//then create a method for that

void r_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Text == "test") // e.Result.Text contains the recognized text
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        s.Speak("hello");
        MessageBox.Show("Hi User");
        s.Dispose();
    } 
}
```

So I want the program to change the text of the textbox to the word/phrase which was spoken but was not in the grammar.

ex
`send a mail to xyz`
the sentence is not in the grammar list
so when it is spoken i want

```
textbox1.text = spokenword;
```

what changes should i make to the code for this result.

Comment: If you specifically want the text that is unrecognized, then the `SpeechRecognized` event is not what you need. Other events are available ..?

Comment: @stuartd I want the text which was heard by the computer and is not present in the grammar list. Then which event should I use

Comment: @stuard which event should i use??

Answer (score 0):

You can not recognize words which are not in the grammar. You just need to make bigger grammar. In case you want to recognize arbitrary text you can use DictationGrammar, it should cover most of the words.

Once text is recognized you can assign it to a text box:

```
 textbox1.text = e.Result.Text;
```